# block all ads in one website or more, with a userscript

Tags: javascript, ads, greasemonkey, userscripts, adblock

I use Google Chrome with its common userscript manager Tampermonkey, in which I have a list of websites:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         blocksite
// @match        *://*.site1.com/*
// @match        *://*.site2.com/*
// ==/UserScript==
```

I desire to block all ads in all websites of the group.
My problem is that I don't know how to even start to try to do that;
I found no clear explanation or tutorial when Googling the following question:

> how does an adblocker work?

or

> How to block websites in Greasemonkey?

I also tried to download the seemingly "innocent" Chrome extension [AdBlock Plus](https://github.com/adblockplus/adblockpluschrome) but in its folder I found a multitude of JavaScript files (many of which are above 500 lines) and felt "lost" trying to figure out where and how to start studying the source code (what's relevant and irrelevant for writing a small blocker script for personal usage) and what is the reason for this complexity.

Assuming blocking ads with a userscript manager is an easy task with latest ECMAScript release (10), I'd like to ask as a JavaScript amateur:
**How could I block all ads in one website or more, with userscript?**

Comment: i think you'd be better served using the extension runtime, \_\_monkey is going to be too high level and too late to stop the ad loading. You can _hide_ ads with userscripts, i do that myself on a few stubborn cases, but it's hard or impossible to prevent them.

Comment: Ads are just normal DOM things, not some separate entity, and ES version doesn't have any relation to this. You'll have to check for lots of things like words in image/iframe urls, typical banner image sizes, and so on. Generally this is a super broad topic, but if you're lucky and your ads have a distinct telltale you could remove them using a userscript, indeed. We can't help you though without seeing the actual sites or a proper [MCVE](/help/mcve). P.S. userscript managers can't block any ads, they only manage/install/run userscripts.

Comment: @wOxxOm for example mako.co.il; I just want to say I never claimed or intended to claim that userscript managers block websites by them selves; if you want, please share where the question indicated that and I will likely edit.

Comment: You've mentioned it twice: "blocking ads with a userscript manager [...]" and "block all ads with userscript manager?" I guess you meant "with a userscript". As for that site, you can use MutationObserver to detect when elements are added to `document.body` and delete them if they match various criteria that you'll deduce by inspecting DOM in devtools.

Comment: Sorry for the bad phrasing - indeed I meant to "with userscript". Thank you for the helpful comment indicating observing for mutations and delete them if they match one or more criterions.